# What typings for leaflet library means?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I have a question about [@typings/leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet). There is typing definition for TileLayer in index.d.ts:

```
class TileLayer extends GridLayer {
    constructor(urlTemplate: string, options?: TileLayerOptions);
    setUrl(url: string, noRedraw?: boolean): this;

    options: TileLayerOptions;
}
```

But the implementation class in [leaflet](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js) has many other methods besides setUrl. How this is going to help Angular 4 developer to import TileLayer without having to load the whole leaflet.js in index.html?

Also in the implementation class TileLayer in leaflet.js is defined under L namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Declarations files (`*.d.ts`) allow you to use third party libraries in typescript, because javascript is dynamically typed, in order to achieve "compile time type checking", typescript needs to know the type of each symbol, and these declaration files allow typescript to do that.

For example, typescript itself comes with this declaration file that contains the declaration for `document.querySelector()`, and this function returns an `Element`, in plain javascript, you can do this `document.querySelector(...).style` with no problem, but in typescript, it complains because, the interface `Element` has no property called `style`, so you need to cast it to `HTMLElement`, then typescript will be happy. It can do this because of the `.d.ts` derclaration file

Comment: this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The other methods type/signature declarations comes by inheritance. This does the trick:

`class TileLayer extends GridLayer {`

Also, If you're using a script loader like RequireJS or even a package bundler like Webpack, the Leaflet components not necessarily will be inside the global "L", because it will be loaded using injection. Leaflet provides the script wrapped in a UMD pattern that checks all type of loaders (amd, commonjs, commonjs2, etc) before export it in the "L" global.

About your question of loading the whole Leaflet in your code. Some plugins can aggressively check you final bundle and remove pieces of code that isn't used, like function/method calls. Webpack is pretty good doing this also. The other options should be try load the separated components (and they dependencies) from the source code, but I don't advise to do that, because differently from libraries as core-js, they didn't design Leaflet to load in this way.

tip: If you're using TypeScript, you shouldn't be including the dependencies in index.html, let babel/webpack/systemjs do it for you ;)